# Android: How to marquee all views in Linear Layout which has Horizontal orientation?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have made a `Linear Layout` and i am adding views (only `TextView`) to it dynamically everytime a key in `EditText` is pressed which further calls a query method to update the `LinearLayout` and inflate it with views.

activity_main.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >
    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
private void autoCompleteText() {

    int i = 0;
    current_search = editText1.getText().toString();
    String val = "";
    // arr is an array of strings
    for (String str : arr) { 
        if (str.startsWith(current_search)) {

            final TextView t = new TextView(_context);

            t.setId(i++);
            t.setLayoutParams(p);
            t.setBackgroundResource(color.holo_blue_bright);
            t.setText(str);

            linLayout.addView(t);

            t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(_context, String.valueOf(t.getId())+ " "+ t.getX(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want a single `TextView` to appear in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: So what do you want instead of a textview?

Comment: @Gianfranco i want multiple textviews to marquee.